# How To Delete Sidekiq Scheduled job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I stucked in a problem, I don't know how to delete sidekiq scheduled jobs
I tried with lots of methods but not succeeded

Below is my code :-

```
class UpdatePopularityWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'es_sync'

  def perform(city_id=nil)
    clear_popularity_jobs(city_id) 
    time = ENV['UPDATE_POPULARITY'].present? ? ENV['UPDATE_POPULARITY'].to_i : 60.minutes
    UpdatePopularityWorker.perform_in(time, city_id)
  end

  private

  def clear_popularity_jobs(city_id) 
    queued_jobs = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new("es_sync")
    jobs = queued_jobs.select{|retri| 
      retri.args == 'UpdatePopularityWorker' 
    }
    jobs.each(&:delete)
  end
end
```

But after execution I get below error :-

```
{"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"class":"UpdatePopularityWorker","args":[],"retry":true,"queue":"es_sync","jid":"db75d1e92933dfad69449dfa","created_at":1568050410.422802,"enqueued_at":1568050410.423174,"error_message":"wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)"
```

And when I tried to execute in console then also I get error for wrong argument :-

```
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new("es_sync")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Please somebody suggest or help me with this situation.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 11):

You just need to find Scheduled jobs and delete it with any condition that matches with your codebase.

```
queue = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
queue.each do |job|
  job.delete if (job.klass == 'Notification' && job.args.first == id)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The error describes the problem:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

You want:

```
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
```

Comment: But I need to get jobs according to specific queue. Is this possible or not?

Comment: because my schedule queue is too large.

Comment: A queue holds jobs that are ready to execute **right now**. Any scheduled jobs are held in the ScheduledSet until the time is ready for them to be enqueued. Your job is not in a queue yet.

Comment: As the API page makes clear, scanning and deleting jobs with the API is very slow.  This is not the right path to go down.  Either use cancellation or use dynamic cron jobs to kick off work immediately -- don't schedule it if it might not run.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow below steps:

```
ss = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
jobs = ss.scan("SomeWorker").select {|retri| retri.klass == 'SomeWorker' }
jobs = ss.select {|retri| retri.klass == 'SomeWorker' }
jobs.each(&:delete)
```

Answer (score 3):

```rb
def delete_scheduled_jobs
    Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.each do |job|
      job.delete if job.queue.to_sym == :job_name_queue
    end
end
```

Comment: Please add some explaination